# Use different Sourcefiles in .bbappend (Immediate variable expansion)

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe

we are using yocto and bulding two slightly different images. One is just the standard image "bitbake standard-image" and the other one is a debug-image "bitbake debug-image" where additional programs, etc will be deployed. In both recipes the variable IMAGE_TYPE (=standard/debug) will be set. This variable should be used to deploy different "sshd_conf"-files to the image. To achieve this I edited the "openssh_%.append"-file which looked original like this:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/openssh:"

SRC_URI += " \
        file://sshd_config \
"
```

and now looks like this :

```
python () {
    if d.getVar('IMAGE_TYPE') == 'debug':
        d.appendVar('FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend', '${THISDIR}/debug:')
        d.appendVar('SRC_URI', ' \\ file://sshd_config \\ ')


    if d.getVar('IMAGE_TYPE') == 'standard':
        d.appendVar('FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend', '${THISDIR}/openssh:')
        d.appendVar('SRC_URI', ' \\ file://sshd_config \\ ')
}
```

My Problem is that it doesnt work like intended. With the modification I did none of mine "sshd_config"-files gets deployed. Instead the default "sshd_conf" which comes with the layer is deployed.
I think my problem is that the variable "${THISDIR}" is not immediate expanded, but i dont know how to do that in "anonymous Python functions".

Does someone know how to make my changes work?
Maybe this is not the way to go, is there a better way to deploy different files for different images ?

Thanks in advance
Heiko

Comment: try `d.prependVar('FILESEXTRAPATHS' ... `

Comment: Check out https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#functions-for-accessing-datastore-variables

Comment: thanks @Nayfe .
Another comment (which vanished now somehow) pointed out i should make sure that my "if"-clause gets entered. with the help of "bb.plain" i noticed that the python function gets entered but not my "if"-clauses. i dont know why it doesnt enter the if-clauses because I sue the same construct in an .bbclass and there it works. why is the variable not set when i tried to read it in a recipe but set when i read this in a .bbclass ??

Comment: It's maybe a easier way to set IMAGE_TYPE in local.conf or distro configuration, to have this accessible globally?

Comment: Also be careful as `IMAGE_TYPES` (with S) already exists :)

Comment: @Heiko, yes I did remove the comment as I guessed you would have verified that at some point (after reading it I thought it was an obvious recommendation; general debug workflow...). I'd set `IMAGE_TYPE` in `local.conf` as @Nayfe points out.

Comment: hi danlor thanks for your input, sometimes also the obvoius or easy stuff is really helpful. yeah i should have checked that myself (i didnt know how and didnt know about bb.plain, the mega manual is quit big and i still try to get a grip on yocto )
also pinging @Nayfe : my problem with "setting this variable in the local.conf" is that we dont have the local.conf checked in into our git-repo (so everybody can have his own local.conf because of settings some own paths etc)

im still confused about the fact that i can read this variable in a .bbclass but not in a recipe

Comment: don't you have a custom distro configuration file?

Comment: Yes I do have a custom distro config file. But i want to distinguish between debug and standard image. How do i do that in the distro-config?
I think I will take your hint and try to read some stuff up, i feel like my knowledge about how the distro conf is invoked and so on is not enough atm.

Comment: for instance, you can set `IMAGE_TYPE ??= "standard"` in your distro config file then override it in local.conf if you want debug version

Comment: Hey @Nayfe thanks for the solution I really appreciate your help! (especially since Im probably asking dump questions)
After playing a bit with "setting my var in distro conf" i can see your solution to be working. 

Since the two different images are already build by calling different recipes ("bitbake standard-image/debug-image") I want to circumvent manual editing the local.conf. Maybe, having different recipes for standard-image/debug-image this is not the way to do it in yocto, but thats the way I found it to be done at our project.

Comment: another solution is to tweak configuration in image recipe via ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND

Comment: I'm not sure whether this works at all! Somewhere I read that a package will only be built once, for each "variant" (there are variants "native", "native-sdk", besides the default variant, I think). I thought you can't build a package twice, once for each image. I'm happy to be disproven though. Maybe the restriction was that yocto will rebuild the package if you build the second image, and the new build replaces the previous build, instead of adding a variant.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use `d.prependVar("FILESEXTRAPATHS", ...)` not `d.appendVar("FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend", ...)`.

We tried your approach as well (in Python), and for us it failed since `${THISDIR}` was not expanded to the directory in which the `.bbappend` file was stored, but the parent directory of the original `.bb` file. Maybe that is (or was) a bitbake bug?

How about a subdirectory per image type with the respective name (no Python block needed):

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files_${IMAGE_TYPE}:"
```

This does not exactly what you want (subdirectory name is not the same as the image type), but it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually describing the purpose of [DISTRO_FEATURES](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-DISTRO_FEATURES).

**Fair warning** that this wont work exactly as you thought of it initially because that's not how the system is designed to work, but it is possible to achieve.

#### Ok, first, Why doesn't your solution work?

It doesn't work because you are trying to achieve this at an **IMAGE level**, and `bitbake` does not allow the `IMAGE` "scope" to access/modify other recipes behaviour.

This means that setting a variable on `image1.bb` (in your case `standard-image.bb`) wont have any effect on `recipeA.bb` (in your case `openssh.bbappend`) since neither `recipeA.bb` can access the variables of `image1.bb` nor `image1.bb` can access the variables of `recipeA.bb`, this is by design.

Hence for your scenario, when you're trying to read the `IMAGE_TYPE` variable inside the `openssh.bbappend` via anonymous python:

```
if d.getVar('IMAGE_TYPE') == 'debug':
```

Nothing happens because for all `openssh.bb` knows, that variable isn't even set.

Here's where `DISTRO` comes into play, you **CAN** modify the behaviour of different recipes depending on which `DISTRO` you are building, that's precisely the reason `DISTRO_FEATURES` exist.

You can find several examples in the existing codebase, lets look at [wpa_supplicant](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/recipes-connectivity/wpa-supplicant/wpa-supplicant_2.10.bb#n81) for a simple one:

```
if ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES','systemd','true','false',d)}; then
        install -d ${D}/${systemd_system_unitdir}
        install -m 644 ${S}/wpa_supplicant/systemd/*.service ${D}/${systemd_system_unitdir}
fi
```

if `systemd` is part of the `DISTRO_FEATURES` for the `DISTRO` being built, then `bitbake` will install additional files (systemd services in this case) for this package

Hence, if you add systemd to your `DISTRO_FEATURES` in your `DISTRO.conf` by something like:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " systemd"
```

You'll get those files in your image (regardless of which image you are building), if systemd is not there those files wont be there on the resulting image either.

You can do the something similar an add a "my-debug-feature" to your distros:

```
DISTRO_FEATURE:append = " my-debug-feature"
```

and then on the recipe essentially do the same check as above:

```
if ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES','my-debug-feature','true','false',d)}; then
        install -m 644 ${S}/sshd_standard_config ${D}/${sysconfdir}/sshd_config
else
        install -m 644 ${S}/sshd_debug_config ${D}/${sysconfdir}/sshd_config
fi
```

There are several other examples you can find [bluez](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/recipes-connectivity/bluez5/bluez5.inc#n18), [connman](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/recipes-connectivity/connman/connman.inc#n37), [inetutils](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/recipes-connectivity/inetutils/inetutils_2.4.bb#n30), which modify installation or modify recipe's behavior in some way if a certain `DISTRO_FEATURE` is present.

Now, I know you thought of this by using two images and you may find this answer frustrating, so, you can certainly have two images and not two DISTROs but it needs to be architected in a different way (*The recommended way is still using `DISTRO_FEATURES` though since its cleaner on the long run*).

If you reaaally want to use images instead of separate DISTROs, what you can do is instead of trying to react based on a variable (`IMAGE_TYPE`), simply place the extra files on a different package, e.g. `openssh-standard-config` vs `openssh-debug-config` (These can be separate recipes for simplicity so you dont have to deal as much with conflicts) and on each image install the package that belongs to it.

**standard-image.bb:**

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " openssh-standard-config"
```

**debug-image.bb**

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " openssh-debug-config"
```

You may be tempted to look at [IMAGE_FEATURES](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-IMAGE_FEATURES), but you'll soon realize that it wont allow you to achieve what you want either for the same reason as above